# how to get yesterday date if date is stored in varchar type format is (mm-dd-yyyy) for Event scheduler

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called time where date column store date in varchar type format is (m-d-y)

I'm running an event at 1am every night inserting the data into the daily data table form time table.
in below formula i have given the A.Date value of yesterday (example if today (01-12-2019) at 1AM event run it should pick the date of yesterday(01-11-2019)

```
INSERT INTO dailydata 
SELECT A.Date, A.EmpID, B.name, B.TeamName, 
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS active,
SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS idle,
Min(A.Statestarttime) AS Stime, MAX(A.StateEndtime) AS Etime,
ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(MAX(A.StateEndtime))/60 - 
TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(A.StateStarttime))/60)/60,2) as Inofficehr, 
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END)/60,2) 
AS activehr, 
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN A.MinutesatState ELSE 0 END)/60,2) 
AS idlehr 
FROM time A join ttld.login B on A.EmpID=B.username 
WHERE A.Date= subdate(current_date, 1) AND A.Statestarttime <>'' AND A.StateEndtime <>'' 
GROUP BY A.EmpID;
```

While running this code i'm getting a

> Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value:

code is working fine if i change `A.Date= subdate(current_date, 1)` to `A.Date='01-13-2019'`, but to make it a event i need some way to get the yesterday date automatically.

I have tried

```
SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(), 1);
SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to convert the string date to a *real* `DATE` datatype before comparing it with another date. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for that purpose.

Try to change :

```
A.Date = subdate(current_date, 1)
```

To :

```
STR_TO_DATE(A.Date, '%m-%d-%Y') = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
```

Comment: STR_TO_DATE is awesome. out of curiosity dose it work for time which is stored in varchar format like 22:15 not able to find the command like STR_TO_DATE for STR_TO_TIME.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the this (first convert varchar to date, then substract 1 day from it)

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2019', '%m/%d/%y%y%y%y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

for using in where clause (index friendly approach)

```
Date =  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 1 DAY), '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to fix your `date` column.  Do not store dates as strings.  Store them as dates.

But if you are, then I would recommend doing the comparison as:

```
A.Date = DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 1) , '%m-%d-%Y')
```

By removing the functions on `A.DATE`, the query can make use of indexes.

```
update time
    set date = str_to_date(date, '%m-%d-%Y');  -- this will set the string to the default format for a date

alter table time modify date date;
```

Also note that `date` and `time` are poor choices for column and table names because they are already used for both types and functions.